# Происхождение слов "майна" и "вира"

Tags: этимология

Со словом "вира" еще можно предположить, что это искаженное "вверх", а вот откуда взялось слово "майна" и "майнать"?

Comment: Был в Италии. Спрашивал. Итальянец сказал что таких слов в их языке нет. Команды поднимай и опускай по другому. Вот так. А я всю жизнь считал , что это с итальянского языка.

Comment: Неправильный итальянец попался!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вира - команда при погрузке, разгрузке: поднимай!, вверх! [Ит. virare - вращать (лебёдку), поворачивать.] 
Майна - команда при погрузке, разгрузке: опускай!, вниз! [Ит. maina - убирай, опускай, от ammainare - убирать (паруса), спускать (флаг).]. К нам попало, скорей всего, через черноморских генуэзцев.

Comment: Словам явно два, много - три, века. А генуэзцам?

Answer (score 4):

Глагол ***ammainare*** переводится как "спускать паруса, флаг", а вот ***virare*** в одном из своих значений переводится как "совершать маневр (о водных судах и самолетах), изменяющий направление движения".
При этом "vira" в современном ит. языке - это повелительное наклонение, т.е. "поворачивай, буквально, маневрируй". Возможно, команда "вира" не означает "поднимать", а сигнал о том, что груз зацеплен, и посему можно производить его перемещение, что в мире маневровых лебедок и называется "маневр".

Answer (score 2):

Переношу посты с грамоты:

> А это с "Лингвофорума":
> Фасмер говорит
> Из ит. virare "поворачивать"
> от ит. (am)mainare "спускать (паруса)"
> Заимствованная морская терминология, относились слова к подъему-спуску парусов.

(Maggie)

> Вообще-то в одном Фасмер прав. Все эти команды пришли от моряков. А на море, как известно, всегда всё международное.
> Вот насчёт происхождения - не уверен. Боюсь,что никакого осмысленного генезиса у них может и не быть. Выбрана случайная звучная комбиначия - и вперёд. Все наиболее "правдоподобные" объяснения при ближайшем рассмотрении оказываются надуманными. Тот же случай, что с OK или SOS.
> Версия Фасмера кажется мне неочевидной по причине довольно странного выбора исходных смысловых глаголов.

(behemothus)

Продолжение - тут: 
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1705

А вот уже "битва гигантов" с той еще, гремевшей на весь рунет "Грамоты".
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=14&i=4637&t=4509
Без специальной (психологической) подготовки можно и не читать))).

PS Глагол maina в итальянском отсутствует. По крайней мере - в современном.
Есть глагол ***ammainare*** - спускать (паруса). 
А ***virare*** значит поворачивать (лебедку, видимо). Совсем не "поднимать". 
Само по себе это ничего не опровергает. Но заставляет задуматься.

Answer (score -1):

«майна» и «вира» - это морские термины древних финикийцев. Вира (вверх) – буквально означает «в воздух» (ср. ивр. «овира») , майна (вниз) - буквально, «в воду» (ср. ивр. «маима») . 
цивиливизации финикийцев давно нет, но много слов с их языка встречается в немецком и итальянском.... и эти слова пришли в итальянский язык, а в России в свое время было много итальянских архитекторов. которые руководя строительством на своем языке использовали эти слова... вот и пришли в русский язык эти термины и закрепились как у строителей, так и в морских доках..

Comment: Фантазии. А почему не древних папуасов?